# Flash AS3 SharedObject data not saved between builds

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, shared-objects

Trying to save some local data on an iOS/Android game made in AS3 using SharedObject but whenever we have a new build all the data is erased.  Is there a way to get sharedObjects to work between builds of the app or is there another way I should be going about doing save data and any tutorials on how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: IOS might not allow you to share data between builds, so you'd better implement server side data storage, POSTing the data there should be completely hidden, and GETting should be performed whenever there is no local data available, either due to any kind of malfunction on the client, or version update.

Comment: use the application storage folder and save your data there in txt files or whatever. This will not be erased.